# Need help getting a modal to appear on a webpage with cards

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Im working on a program that consists of a webpage generated with cards. I want to make it so when you click on one of the cards a modal pops up but Im having some difficulty. The overlay part works whenever one of the cards is pressed but the modal wont appear.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Fish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c502137733.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-warning">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 jumbotron mb-3 team-heading bg-primary">
                <h1 class="text-center text-warning" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Fish</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="openmodal" data-modal-target="#modal">Open Modal</div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="title">Example Modal</div>
      <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse quod alias ut illo doloremque eum ipsum obcaecati distinctio debitis reiciendis quae quia soluta totam doloribus quos nesciunt necessitatibus, consectetur quisquam accusamus ex, dolorum, dicta vel? Nostrum voluptatem totam, molestiae rem at ad autem dolor ex aperiam. Amet assumenda eos architecto, dolor placeat deserunt voluptatibus tenetur sint officiis perferendis atque! Voluptatem maxime eius eum dolorem dolor exercitationem quis iusto totam! Repudiandae nobis nesciunt sequi iure! Eligendi, eius libero. Ex, repellat sapiente!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {{ team }}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Put more code here to try to see the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.